# How to Convert One Part of an Excel Formula to Values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to convert only one section of an excel formula to 'values' using VBA. It's important that the resulting formula lands in a single cell, so I can't just convert one cell to values and leave another live. To use an example, the beginning formula below refers to two sheets, one internal to the workbook and one external.

Essentially, I want to make it so that the Internal reference stays live but the external reference is converted to a value. I've tried using the link breaking function but unfortunately this kills the whole formula.

Beginning Formula:

```
=MATCH(A4,InternData!$A:$A,0)+MATCH(A4,[ExternalWorkbook.xlsx]ExternData!$A:$A,0)
```

Desired Result:

```
=MATCH(A4,InternData!$A:$A,0)+ [Value that would be generated by external match function]
```

Comment: `worksheetfunction` or `evaluate` may help, what have you tried so far?  Will the other workbook be open?  What about updates in the other workbook, the static value wont change.

Answer (score 1):

Lop through the column you plan to put the formula into.

This assumes ExternalWorkbook.xlsx is already open in the workbooks collection.

The row number returned from the external match is not error controlled against #N/A no match errors.

```
dim i as long, lr as long, erng as range

set erng = workbooks("ExternalWorkbook.xlsx").worksheets("ExternData").columns("A")

with thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet1")

    lr = .cells.count(.rows.count, "A").end)xlup).row

    for i = 4 to lr

        .cells(i, "B").formula = _
          "=match(a" & i & ", InternData!$A:$A, 0)+" & application.match(.cells(i, "A").value, erng , 0)

    nrxt i

end with
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Application.Evaluate.  In my example I have the following data on a spreadsheet:

```
A1: 5
B1: 2
C1: 3
A3: =A1+SUM(B1:C1)
```

You can then run this code to convert A3's formula to `=A1+5`.  Clearly you'll need to adjust everything to fit your situation & **definitely** put in error handling or you'll be modifying formulae with little control!

```
Sub bob()
    Dim tmpFirst    As String
    Dim tmpSecond   As String

    tmpFirst = Split(Range("A3").Formula, "+")(0)
    tmpSecond = Split(Range("A3").Formula, "+")(1)

    Range("A3").Formula = tmpFirst & "+" & Application.Evaluate(tmpSecond)
End Sub
```

The Split function splits on the `+` which is very likely going to be problematic.  I'd recommend adding a dummy named range called `Spacer` or similar, which points to a cell with a value of zero maybe?  The formula could then be something like:
`=A1+Spacer+SUM(B1:C1)`

and the Split could then be done on `+Spacer+` instead of `+` to avoid splitting on a plus sign that you don't want to (could easily happen).

Comment: Also, instead of relying on a particular position following the split, you could check each of the elements returned by the split to see if it contains an external reference and apply the Evaluate function if required.  

You'd then reassemble the bits as appropriate into the final formula.